# How much would it cost for a Turkish citizen to obtain a Mexico visa

Tags: visas, mexico, turkish-citizens

According to Wikipedia, Turkish citizens only need some online authorization rather than a visa to enter Mexico. Is that correct? How much does it cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online authorization you mentioned is the Electronic Authorization System (SAE) or electronic visa which allows Russian, Ukrainian and **Turkish citizens** to obtain an electronic authorization to travel to Mexico without a consular visa. According to the [website](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/turquia/index.php/consular-services/electronic-visa) of Mexican Embassy in Turkey it's **free**:

> 1. The electronic visa (SAE) is available only for Holders of Turkish [ordinary (BORDO) passports](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/turquia/images/bordo.jpg).
> 2. Holders of Turkish special (green) and service (grey) passports must apply in the nearest consular office of Mexico for the
>      corresponding stamped visa.
> 3. The electronic visa (SAE) is valid for 30 days since issuing date and a single entry. The holders could stay for a period up to 180
>      days*.
> 4. **The electronic visa (SAE) is FREE**. Do not accept charges to obtain it.
> 5. The electronic visa (SAE) is available only if you are traveling by air with an airline incorporated to SAE. If you want to entry by
>      land or by sea, it is necessary to apply for a visa in the nearest
>      consular office of Mexico.

At the point of entry, the migratory agent will require the following documentation:

> 1. [FMM form dully filled](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html)
> 2. Hotel bookings in Mexico and return or onward flight ticket.
> 3. Documents proving the purpose of the trip (tour itinerary, company invitations, company contract, etc)
> 4. Proof of financial means.

Comment: Is there a list of airlines incorporated to SAE?

Comment: That's a good question, but it's something that you will most probably learn directly by contacting airlines ([like this user](https://www.facebook.com/airfrance/posts/10152185957900526)) after finding an interesting offer. Alternatively, maybe you can ask a new question here.

Comment: [Another example](https://twitter.com/klm/status/233612826189647873?lang=en). I couldn't find any specific list in the web though, you should definitely contact directly the airlines.